# T-SQL insert with output expression

Tags: t-sql, insert, output-clause

```
insert Table1
OUTPUT inserted.ID, s.[Id] 
INTO @Inserted
select 
s.[Field1],
s.[Field2],
from 
@TableVariable s
```

why is `s.[Id]`  marked by red line ? Is it non-correct syntax to save value in `@Inserted` table variable ?

Comment: You can run the query and it will throw an error to help you troubleshoot. You can double click the error in SSMS and it will point out in the window where the error is.  However, the syntax for this query is overall wrong. Google how to write an insert into and google syntax for using output/output with a join.

Comment: If you want to create some kind of mapping, there's a [method involving MERGE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365629/using-merge-output-to-get-mapping-between-source-id-and-target-id).

Comment: I found an answer as well as example here http://stackoverflow.com/a/1786653/5173754

Comment: @DotNetGoose - edit your question to clearly show the design of the tables and variables involved.  Without that, it's difficult to provide an answer that has clarity.

Answer (score 2):

s is not valid
at that point you only have inserted

if you want the fields then try

```
OUTPUT inserted.ID, inserted.[Field1], inserted.[Field2]
```

instead of line 2 in your query.  You can find more here:

[OUTPUT Clause (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: but how can i map new ID on an old ID ?

Comment: New ID, old ID?  You are inserting two fields [Field1] and [Field2].  Answer is only as good as the question.  .

Comment: one of them is a new id an another one is an old id

Comment: it has Identity property, so its an id

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ i called it "old" then that is old :)

Comment: "It"  - we are supposed to know what "it" is.  You have two fields in the question - [Field1] and [Field2].   The stated question on syntax - which I answered.

Comment: @dotnetgoose is that comma after field 2 in your actual query?

Comment: thanks to all, a problem solved with `merge`

Comment: Glad every think worked out for YOU.   Because you of your lack of clarity it will  be of little to no value to others.